# SparkContext cannot be launched in the same programe with Streaming SparkContext

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I created the following test that fit a simple linear regression model to a dummy streaming data.
I use hyper-parameters optimisation to find good values of `stepSize`, `numiterations` and `initialWeights` of the linear model.
Everything runs fine, except the last lines of the code that are commented out:

```
// Save the evaluations for further visualization
// val gridEvalsRDD = sc.parallelize(gridEvals)
//      gridEvalsRDD.coalesce(1)
//        .map(e => "%.3f\t%.3f\t%d\t%.3f".format(e._1, e._2, e._3, e._4))
//        .saveAsTextFile("data/mllib/streaming")
```

The problem is with the SparkContext `sc`. If I initialize it at the beginning of a test, then the program shown errors. It looks like `sc` should be defined in some special way in order to avoid conflicts with `scc` (streaming spark context). Any ideas?

The whole code:

```
    // scalastyle:off
    package org.apache.spark.mllib.regression

    import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.{Vector, Vectors}
    import org.apache.spark.mllib.util.LinearDataGenerator
    import org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream
    import org.apache.spark.streaming.{StreamingContext, TestSuiteBase}
    import org.apache.spark.streaming.TestSuiteBase
    import org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfter

    class StreamingLinearRegressionHypeOpt  extends TestSuiteBase with BeforeAndAfter {

      // use longer wait time to ensure job completion
      override def maxWaitTimeMillis: Int = 20000

      var ssc: StreamingContext = _

      override def afterFunction() {
        super.afterFunction()
        if (ssc != null) {
          ssc.stop()
        }
      }

      def calculateMSE(output: Seq[Seq[(Double, Double)]], n: Int): Double = {
        val mse = output
          .map {
            case seqOfPairs: Seq[(Double, Double)] =>
              val err = seqOfPairs.map(p => math.abs(p._1 - p._2)).sum
              err*err
          }.sum / n
        mse
      }

      def calculateRMSE(output: Seq[Seq[(Double, Double)]], n: Int): Double = {
          val mse = output
            .map {
              case seqOfPairs: Seq[(Double, Double)] =>
                val err = seqOfPairs.map(p => math.abs(p._1 - p._2)).sum
                err*err
            }.sum / n
          math.sqrt(mse)
      }

      def dummyStringStreamSplit(datastream: Stream[String]) =
        datastream.flatMap(txt => txt.split(" "))


      test("Test 1") {
        // create model initialized with zero weights
        val model = new StreamingLinearRegressionWithSGD()
          .setInitialWeights(Vectors.dense(0.0, 0.0))
          .setStepSize(0.2)
          .setNumIterations(25)

        // generate sequence of simulated data for testing
        val numBatches = 10
        val nPoints = 100
        val inputData = (0 until numBatches).map { i =>
          LinearDataGenerator.generateLinearInput(0.0, Array(10.0, 10.0), nPoints, 42 * (i + 1))
        }

        // Without hyper-parameters optimization
        withStreamingContext(setupStreams(inputData, (inputDStream: DStream[LabeledPoint]) => {
          model.trainOn(inputDStream)
          model.predictOnValues(inputDStream.map(x => (x.label, x.features)))
        })) { ssc =>
          val output: Seq[Seq[(Double, Double)]] = runStreams(ssc, numBatches, numBatches)

          val rmse = calculateRMSE(output, nPoints)
          println(s"RMSE = $rmse")
        }


        // With hyper-parameters optimization
        val gridParams = Map(
          "initialWeights" -> List(Vectors.dense(0.0, 0.0), Vectors.dense(10.0, 10.0)),
          "stepSize" -> List(0.1, 0.2, 0.3),
          "numIterations" -> List(25, 50)
        )

        val gridEvals = for (initialWeights <- gridParams("initialWeights");
                             stepSize <- gridParams("stepSize");
                             numIterations <- gridParams("numIterations")) yield {
          val lr = new StreamingLinearRegressionWithSGD()
                      .setInitialWeights(initialWeights.asInstanceOf[Vector])
                      .setStepSize(stepSize.asInstanceOf[Double])
                      .setNumIterations(numIterations.asInstanceOf[Int])


          withStreamingContext(setupStreams(inputData, (inputDStream: DStream[LabeledPoint]) => {
            lr.trainOn(inputDStream)
            lr.predictOnValues(inputDStream.map(x => (x.label, x.features)))
          })) { ssc =>
            val output: Seq[Seq[(Double, Double)]] = runStreams(ssc, numBatches, numBatches)
            val cvRMSE = calculateRMSE(output, nPoints)
            println(s"RMSE = $cvRMSE")
            (initialWeights, stepSize, numIterations, cvRMSE)
          }
        }

        // Save the evaluations for further visualization
        // val gridEvalsRDD = sc.parallelize(gridEvals)
        //      gridEvalsRDD.coalesce(1)
        //        .map(e => "%.3f\t%.3f\t%d\t%.3f".format(e._1, e._2, e._3, e._4))
        //        .saveAsTextFile("data/mllib/streaming")

      }

}
// scalastyle:on
```

Comment: try to get the context from ssc.sparkContext, so that would be ssc.sparkContext.parallelize

Comment: @psoucy: if I do so and execute the code, it throws `java.lang.NullPointerException was thrown` at the line `val gridEvalsRDD = ssc.sparkContext.parallelize(gridEvals)`